# Use @ClassRule in Kotlin

Tags: junit4, kotlin

In JUnit you can use @ClassRule to annotate an static field.
How can I do this in Kotlin?

I tried:

```
object companion {
    @ClassRule @JvmStatic
    val managedMongoDb = ...    
}

and 

object companion {
    @ClassRule @JvmField
    val managedMongoDb = ...    
}
```

but none of the last works because rule isn't executed.

I double checked that exactly same rule works fine without static context:

```
@Rule @JvmField
val managedMongoDb = ...
```

Comment: what the difference between first two versions?

Comment: One uses @JvmStatic and other JvmField. To my understand as I want to reproduce a static field the first is the one to use, but I tried also with the second.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are not using [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) correctly.  You are declaring an object (single instance of a class) called `companion` instead of creating a `companion object` inside of a class.  And therefore the static fields are not created correctly.

```
class TestClass {
    companion object { ... }
}
```

Is very different than:

```
class TestClass { 
    object companion { ... } // this is an object declaration, not a companion object
}
```

Although both are valid code.

Here is a correct working example of using `@ClassRule`, tested in Kotlin 1.0.0:

```
class TestWithRule {
    companion object {
        @ClassRule @JvmField
        val resource: ExternalResource = object : ExternalResource() {
            override fun before() {
                println("ClassRule Before")
            }

            override fun after() {
                println("ClassRule After")
            }
        }
    }

    @Test fun testSomething() {
        println("Testing...")
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> ClassRule Before 
>   Testing...
>   ClassRule After

Comment: `object companion { ... }` is not an object expression but an object declaration as per https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html.